# Using Single Image for Hover Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Had read somewhere on a webtutorial that we can use only a single Image for hover effects in css. For Eg. I Need to input only this image in CSS

[image: CSS Image]

So, When the Facebook Icon is not hover we see the dull grey icon, but when someone hovers over the icon, the blue icon is displayed and I need to use only one image file in the CSS for this purpose.

How Can we do that. Also, I would like to know what are these kind of images know as ?

Comment: '[Image sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)' is what they're known as.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

They allow you to use one image for multiple elements, that can look entirely different

[Official Documentation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_background_images#Sprites)

I made a quick example to do what you required [here](http://jsfiddle.net/y3u3F/)

```
<div></div>

div {
  background: url('http://i45.tinypic.com/2jee9zo.png');
  background-position: -10px -15px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
}

div:hover {
  background-position: -10px 83px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS sprite. This is a useful tool: http://es.spritegen.website-performance.org/

Further reading: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: w3schools is not "official" documentation and should be used with caution as it has been known to be misleading and inaccurate on a number of topics.

Answer (score 0):

edit: Its called a spirte (sorry added this, cause i forgot to awnser your first question how this was named)

You can do this by positioning your background image as in example from my work down below

This is CSS, btw

```
input#searchSubmit          { height: 34px; width: 36px; background: url('../images/searchSubmit.png') no-repeat; margin: 8px 8px 0 4px; cursor: pointer; border: none; }
input#searchSubmit:hover    { background-position: 0px -34px; }
```

As you see, as I hover over the searchSubmit , it will change the background position of the image, pasted on the button, showing instead of the black with red search icon, the red with white search icon.

site is here, so you can see it in action, all my action buttons are made this way btw. 
[click here for seeing this in action](http://darktiderising.net/newHolo/)